# How to display a link which will show pop-up

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, semantics

I have a table with some text data. One of the columns should be clickable: a pop-up for editing this row will appear.

What is the best way to explain for user that clicking on this row will cause a pop-up?
I see 4 variants:

1. Hyperlink
   `<td><a href="#">Smith</a></td>`
   Not good cause usually links open new pages.
2. Dotted-underline link
   `<td><span style="cursor:pointer; border-bottom: dotted 1px">Jackson</span></td>`
   User will expect a hovering help window.
3. Button
   `<td><button>Doe</button></td>`
   Looks bad and also not clear what will happen after click.
4. Clickable icon
   `<td>Johnson <span style="cursor:pointer" class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span>`
   I'd like to avoid repeating the same element many times.

[Here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yshylov/Ugc9C/1) with all of these variants.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The icon is the most appealing as the other ones just show that you will be taken to more info. While the icon is clear that the user will edit.

I would also make it a hover affect for it like so:

```
$(document).ready(function() {     
    $('#test2').hover(function(){     
        $('#test').addClass('glyphicon glyphicon-edit');    
    },     
    function(){    
        $('#test').removeClass('glyphicon glyphicon-edit');     
    });
});
```

the `#test2` is the cell and `#test` is the span.

http://jsfiddle.net/Ugc9C/2/

Comment: When a new user will look into such table, he won't even know that the column values are clickable

Comment: @YuriiShylov it was just an idea, it may come in handy one day.